# Eclipse IDE with ADT add in

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse but every time I open any file from the Project Explorer the Project Explorer closes.

I then have to go to Window > Show View > Project Explorer to get it back to open another file.

Why does it keep disappearing? How can I stop it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset Your Perspective:

```
Window -->Reset Perspective..
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the project explorer view minimized. This means that you can still open the view by clicking the icon, but the view will dissapear to give more room for the editor as soon as the view looses focus.

If this is not the behaviour you want, then choose to restore the view by clicking the restore icon. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-39g.htm) for more information.